# What data type should put for the xsd in the wsdl for images stored as BLOB in the database?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to create a simple web service where the user can retrieve the name price and picture from the database based on the price inputted but i'm getting the error:

> Exception: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Image' property

I'm assuming it must be because i haven't put the right data type in the xsd. Here's the codes for the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<definitions targetNamespace="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:this="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/wsdl.xsd http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">

<types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice"  elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Input" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:complexType name="DressType">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer"/>
         <xs:element name="Image" type="xs:hexBinary"/> //data type
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfDresses">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="DressPerPrice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="this:DressType"/>
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Result" type="this:ArrayOfDresses"/>
</xs:schema>
</types>

<!--input message-->
<message name="getDressPerPriceRequest">
     <part name="input" element="this:Input"/>
</message>

<!--output message-->
<message name="getDressPerPriceResponse">
     <part name="result" element="this:Result"/>
</message>

<portType name="DressPerPricePortType">
     <operation name="viewDressPerPrice">
         <input message="this:getDressPerPriceRequest"/>
         <output message="this:getDressPerPriceResponse"/>
     </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="DressPerPriceBinding" type="this:DressPerPricePortType">
     <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
     <operation name="viewDressPerPrice">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice"/>
         <input><soap:body use="literal"/></input>
         <output><soap:body use="literal"/></output>
     </operation>
</binding>

<service name="DressPerPriceService">
     <port name="DressPerPricePort" binding="this:DressPerPriceBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost/WebService/Server/Server.php"/>
     </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image really must be stored within the XML, convert it to [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) and use [`xsd:base64Binary`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary) type.

However, if possible, try to store the image apart from the XML file and include in the XML a reference (such as a URL) to the image instead.